# Formgenerator with div

Tags: html, symfony, formbuilder

I want to create forms in symfony2. I need this HTML structur for each control.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Firstname:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control">/div>
</div>
```

Now is my question, how can i add the div with the class `form-group` and how can i surround the input element with the div `.col-md-10`?

```
$builder->add('firstname', 'text', array(
        'attr'   =>  array(
            'class'   => 'form-control'),
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'col-md-2 control-label'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) section of [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

You may need to override the `form_widget` block (`form_widget_compound` block to go into details).

Find [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) the default behavior of each [twig form helper](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig).

The [Form Theming Sub Chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming) contains many relevant examples on how to customize any given form field block.